# after posting with $.post(url,parameters) how to show the answer page as current page?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2, jquery-callback, .post

i am using the following code to send request to the server

```
var url='getDNormalForm.action';
var inputStr="test";
    var simTyp="andOr";
var pars={inputStr:inputStr, simTyp=simTyp};
$.post(url,pars);
```

I have defined my action in struts.xml as follow:

```
        <action name="getDNormalForm" class="ClassNameAction" method="getDNormalForm">
            <result name="andOr">test.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

When I send the post, I can see in firebug the following:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/myProject/getDNormalForm.action 200 OK 23ms
```

and i see in the answer tab the content of the page test.jsp, which means that
I send the post and receive the answer successfully.

My question is: How can I show the page test.jsp as current page?

Comment: Where is the callback? There should be a third parameter in `$.post`

Comment: I tried the following $.post(url,pars, simulate); function simulate(data){ return data.html(data); } but nothing change :(

Comment: If you really want to replace the current page with the result/output of test.jsp, you are not supposed to use an Ajax POST request for this. You should rather revert to the normal page refresh of a form submit. The main reason for using Ajax is that there is no page refresh!

Comment: @AhmedSalah you want to show the content of test.jsp in some div or area of your main JSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post(
  url,
  pars, 
  function(response){
    $("body").html(response);
  }, "html");
```

So the third parameter is the callback function, i.e. the function that is called when the post request finishes (it is asynchronous, meaning that it does not block the execution of the script in browser). jQuery calls that function and passes to it the response as the first argument. Note the 4th parameter - "html", which says what should be the format of the "response" variable (may be text, json, xml, html). Inside the function we just replace the content of the body with the received content.

Comment: what about adding a little description to help out OP understand your code?